# Multiline brace in eqnarray

Tags: latex

I have an **eqnarray** that consists of 3 lines. I would like to have a right brace **}** that spans the last two lines and some brief text explaining these two parts of the equation. Something like

```
foo = bar

    = baz }
          } explain
    = etc }
```

but using one large brace, obviously. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there anything I could add to my answer, since it isn't accepted yet?

Comment: Nope. Just forgot. Now fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is recommended to use `align` instead of `eqnarray` (it gives wrong spacing sometimes). Here is how it can be done with `align`:

```
\begin{align}
    foo & \left.\begin{array}{l} = bar \\ \end{array}\right. \\
        & 
    \left. \begin{array}{l}
        = baz \\
        = etc
    \end{array}\right\} explain
\end{align}
```

The second line's array is just to make the spacing right.

Result will be like this (but of course with equation numbers):

[image]

Comment: You only get one number for the second two equations. Is this sufficient, OP?

Comment: Looks good. I don't need equation numbers for individual lines. Thanks!

Comment: Using \begin{aligned}...\end{aligned} worked better for me than \begin{array}{l}...\end{array} because of consistent line spacing.

Comment: And to save anyone the trouble of looking for this: in order to be able to use `\begin{align}... \end{align}` you should `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: How is it possible to get rid of the little extra space after "foo"?

Comment: @I.Amon you can insert a `\hspace`, which can be of negative width, like `\hspace{-.1cm}`